# How do I append rows with dependent dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

Whenevr I append the row and try to use the dependent dropdown. The value of the apppended rows is change based on the first row.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

           $('#addmoretable').click(function(){

            $('#coursetable').append(
                                  '<tr>'+
                                        '<td>'+
                                            '<div class="form-group">'+
                                                '<select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program_id">'+
                                                    '<?php if($programs): ?>'+
                                                        '<?php foreach($programs as $key => $value): ?>'+
                                                            '<option value="<?= $value -> program_id ?>"><?= $value -> programs ?></option>'+
                                                       ' <?php endforeach; ?>'+
                                                   ' <?php endif; ?>'+
                                                '</select>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+
                                            '<div class="form-group">'+
                                                '<select class="form-control" name="collegeyear_id"></select>'+
                                           ' </div>'+
                                       ' </td>'+
                                      '  <td>'+
                                            '<div class="form-group">'+
                                               ' <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="COURSE...">'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+
                                            '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="COURSE CODE"></div>'+
                                        '</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+
                                            '<div class="form-group">'+
                                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UNITS">'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+
                                            '<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control"></select>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+
                                            '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="remove" type="button"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>'+
                                        '</td>'+
                                   '</tr>'
            );
        });$('select[name="program_id"]').on('change', function() {
            var programID = $(this).val();
            if(programID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?= base_url('/Admin/Dashboard/getcollegeyear/') ?>'+programID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="collegeyear_id"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="collegeyear_id"]').append('<option value="'+ value.collegeyear_id +'">'+ value.collegeyear +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="collegeyear_id"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });


<?= form_open('', 'class=""') ?>


                               <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered" id="coursetable">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>PROGRAM</th>
                                        <th>YEAR LEVEL</th>
                                        <th>COURSE NAME</th>
                                        <th>COURSE CODE</th>
                                        <th>UNITS</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">SEMESTER OFFERED</th>
                                    </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program_id">
                                                    <?php if($programs): ?>
                                                        <?php foreach($programs as $key => $value): ?>
                                                            <option value="<?= $value -> program_id ?>"><?= $value -> programs ?></option>
                                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <select class="form-control" name="collegeyear_id"></select>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="COURSE...">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="COURSE CODE">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UNITS">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <select class="form-control">

                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" id="addmoretable" type="button"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>
                                        </td>
                                   </tr>
                              </table>
                        <?= form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make the id unique by appending the length of row to the id and use that id to the events.

```
var rowCount = $('#coursetable tr').length; // count the row
id="program_id'+rowCount+'" // change this id="program_id" and append rowCount
$("#program_id"+rowCount) //use this instead of this $('select[name="program_id"]') on the events
```

hope this helps.